# Regular expression for language recognized by NFA?

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I am trying to find the regular expression for the language recognized by the following NFA:

$$K=\{1,2,3\},$$

$$\Sigma=\{x,y,z\},$$

$$s(\text{initial state}) = 3,$$

$$F(\text{final state}) = \{1\}.$$

Transition relation $= \{(1,x,2), (3,z,1), (2,y,1), (3, z, 3)\}$

My current idea is that it is $(xyz)^*$ because it has to end with $x, xy$ or $xyz$ and these strings can be looped any number of time but I'm not sure that this is correct.

If anyone had any hints or ideas I would appreciate it very much. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Please clarify what you don't understand and provide additional details to highlight exactly what need being clarified. As it's cuurently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. Basically there are two loops: $ca$ from $q_0$ back to itself and $cb$ from $q_1$ over $q_2$ back to $q_1$. As $q_0$ is our final state, we need to combine those loops to get
$$
L=(c (cb)^* a)^*
$$
Why does this work? If you are in $q_1$ you can either go the $cb$ loop as long as you want or you go $a$ to finish and then you can start again by going to $q_1$ using $c$